# Warn user when switching ui tab

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There is a editor in the tab and if the user has not saved the editor content and switches to other ui tab the unsaved content is lost as the react component unmounts.

I have tried React Router Prompt and this only works when the route url changes. In my case route url doesn't change. I have used material ui tabs.

```
 <Prompt
    when={editorContentSaved}
    message="Are you sure you want to leave?"
 />
```

I tried JavaScript confirm box in useEffect return function, which gets invoked before unmouting but this doesn't stops the user from navigating. Only thing here I can do is decide if user wants to save the content or not. But can't stop navigation.

```
useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
        let confirmValue = window.confirm("Do you want to save the changes?");
    }
})
```

How do I warn the user when route doesn't change but component does change.

Comment: Seems you should some variation of both, one to prevent route transitions and the other to prevent tab transitions. Checking in the `useEffect` cleanup function is too late, the tab the user was on has already unmounted at this point.

Comment: one workaround is that you can disable the material UI tabs that you created until the user does not save the form

Comment: @DrewReese I need to prevent tab transition only. All the solutions I found are related to route transition like react-router promt, setRouteLeaveHook etc. But nothing related to prevent tab transition.

Comment: @4nkitpatel This will affect the UX. My use case is I have to show a modal when switching to other tab without saving the content of current tab.

Answer (score 3):

You can prevent tab change in this manner I suppose:

In the `handleChange` function, you determine if the user is leaving the editor tab and whether you need to stop/warn them or not (i.e. are there any unsaved changes?), if so, you don't change the tab.

Here's an example: (assuming tab `0` is the editor tab)

```js
  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    if (newValue !== 0 && value === 0) {
      const res = window.confirm("Leaving?");
      if (res === true) {
        setValue(newValue);
      }
    } else {
      setValue(newValue);
    }
  };
```

Here's a [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-082ze?file=/demo.js)